# Why zombie processes exist?

Tags: linux, unix, process, fork, zombie-process

Wikipedia says "A child process that terminates but is never waited on by its parent becomes a zombie process." I run this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    pid_t pid, ppid;
    printf("Hello World1\n");
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0)
    {
        exit(0);    
    }
    else
    {
        while(1)
        {
        printf("I am the parent\n");
        printf("The PID of parent is %d\n",getpid());
        printf("The PID of parent of parent is %d\n",getppid());        
        sleep(2);
        }
    }
}
```

This creates a zombie process, but I can't understand why a zombie process is created here?

The output of the program is

```
Hello World1
I am the parent
The PID of parent is 3267
The PID of parent of parent is 2456
I am the parent
The PID of parent is 3267
The PID of parent of parent is 2456
I am the parent
....
.....
```

But why is it that the "child process terminates but is not waited on by its parent" in this case?

Comment: Are you asking why the concept of a zombie process was introduced in Unix? As it stands, the only answer to your question that I see is "because that's how zombie processes are defined".

Comment: **"couldn't understand why zombie process are created here"**
That would be because you aren't calling `wait()` to read the child's exit status, and hence its entry is left behind in the process table.

Comment: Thats ok. But when child runs for some time and exists there isnt any zombie

Comment: Yeah — zombies are the living dead.  Zombie processes have died (either from a signal or because they exited), and the parent process has not yet executed a `wait()` for the process.  The zombie is dead, but still occupies a process table slot and will continue to do so until its parent waits for it, or the parent exits.  If the parent exits, the child will be inherited by the `init` process (usually PID 1), and one of the main purposes of that process (if not the only one) is to wait for children to die.

Comment: The child process executes the `exit(0);`, thus terminating.  The parent process enters an infinite loop without waiting for its child to die. In this context, waiting means 'calls one of the functions `wait()` or `waitpid()`, or one of the various system-dependent alternatives such as `wait3()` or `wait4()`'.  It doesn't just mean 'the parent goes on living'.  When the child doesn't die, there is no possible zombie process; zombie processes are dead.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In your code, zombie is created on `exit(0)` (comment with arrow below):

```
pid=fork();
if (pid==0) {
    exit(0);  // <--- zombie is created on here
} else {
    // some parent code ...
}
```

Why? Because you never `wait`ed on it. When something calls `waitpid(pid)`, it returns postmortem information about process, like its exit code. Unfortunately, when process exited, kernel cannot just dispose of this process entry, or return code will be lost. So it waits for somebody to `wait` on it, and leaves this process entry around  even if it does not really occupy any memory except for entry in process table - this is exactly what is called *zombie*.

**You have few options to avoid creating zombies:**

1. **Add `waitpid()` somewhere in the parent process**. For example, doing this will help:

   ```
   pid=fork();
   if (pid==0) {
       exit(0);    
   } else {
       waitpid(pid);  // <--- this call reaps zombie
       // some parent code ...
   }
   ```
2. **Perform double `fork()`** to obtain grandchild and exit in child while grandchild is still alive. Grandchildren will be automatically adopted by `init` if their parent (our child) dies, which means if grandchild dies, it will be automatically `wait`ed on by `init`. In other words, you need to do something like this:

   ```
   pid=fork();
   if (pid==0) {
       // child
       if (fork()==0) {
           // grandchild
           sleep(1); // sleep a bit to let child die first
           exit(0);  // grandchild exits, no zombie (adopted by init)
       }
       exit(0);      // child dies first
   } else {
        waitpid(pid);  // still need to wait on child to avoid it zombified
        // some parent code ...
   }
   ```
3. **Explicitly ignore SIGCHLD signal in parent**. When child dies, parent gets sent `SIGCHLD` signal which lets it react on children death. You can call `waitpid()` upon receiving this signal, or you can install explicit ignore signal handler (using `signal()` or `sigaction()`), which will make sure that child does not become zombie. In other words, something like this:

   ```
   signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN); // <-- ignore child fate, don't let it become zombie
   pid=fork();
   if (pid==0) {
       exit(0); // <--- zombie should NOT be created here
   } else {
        // some parent code ...
   }
   ```

Comment: Why does ignoring SIGCHLD signal kill the zombie? I understand that it makes sure the child process doesn't become a zombie. So the not-zombie process will quit once the program quits? And a zombie process won't quit once a program quits?

Comment: Again, zombie cannot be killed: its already dead, all that remains is entry in kernel process table. Ignoring SIGCHLD lets kernel know that it's ok to dispose of that entry immediately.