# Cleaning up of child processes

Tags: linux, process

What is actually meant by cleaning up of child processes after it has ended?
In the book Advanced Linux Programming, there is a section on cleaning child processes asynchronously by handling SIGCHLD signal. This signal is sent to the parent process after the termination of child process.

```
sig_atomic_t child_exit_status;
void clean_up_child_process (int signal_number)
{
/* Clean up the child process. */
int status;
wait (&status);
/* Store its exit status in a global variable.
child_exit_status = status;
}
*/
int main ()
{
/* Handle SIGCHLD by calling clean_up_child_process. */
struct sigaction sigchld_action;
memset (&sigchld_action, 0, sizeof (sigchld_action));
sigchld_action.sa_handler = &clean_up_child_process;
sigaction (SIGCHLD, &sigchld_action, NULL);
/* Now do things, including forking a child process.
/* ... */
*/
return 0;
}
```

After catching the signal, the signal handler does nothing except storing the exit status in a global variable. So in this context what is meant by cleaning up of child processes?

Comment: Cleaning up zombie processes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16078985/why-zombie-processes-exist